# how to add LinearLayout as a parent for HackyViewPager in xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager

I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent

activity_view_pager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.test.gallerymoduletest.HackyViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout >
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);

        mViewPager = (HackyViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);

        for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
            photo.add("http://www.test.com/temp/testimages/"+i+".png");
        }

        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), photo));

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            boolean isLocked = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(ISLOCKED_ARG, false);
            ((HackyViewPager) mViewPager).setLocked(isLocked);
        }
    }
```

Comment: remove `setContentView(mViewPager);` n try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

your **HackyViewPager** is already placed in activity layout then no required set as **setContentView(mViewPager)** and you already set your activity layout **setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager)** so simply **remove** this **setContentView(mViewPager)** line.